# Change figures into ppt slides

Tags: matlab, powerpoint

I need to present MATLAB plots and figures in the form of ppt slides.

I tried out using the Publish option in MATLAB,but it is showing all the figures in a single slide. I am looking out for other options so that each figure will be placed in an individual slide.

Is there any other option or how to write the program in MATLAB?

Can you guide me

Answer (score 3):

Break your code into [sections](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-sections-of-programs.html), each section of your published code will get its own slide. This really should be mentioned in the documentation but I don't see it.

Compare the publishing outputs from the following:

```
% One Slide
x = 1:10;
y = 1:10;

h.f1 = figure();
plot(x,y);

h.f2 = figure();
plot(x,y);
```

vs

```
%%
% 3 Slides
x = 1:10;
y = 1:10;

%%
h.f1 = figure();
plot(x,y);

%%
h.f2 = figure();
plot(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the figures as .eps files and simply include those in your ppt. For example:

```
print(h.f1,'-depsc2','NameOfFigure1')

print(h.f2,'-depsc2','NameOfFigure2')
```

Alternatively you can look at: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99150-is-there-an-example-of-using-matlab-to-create-powerpoint-slides